# What to do when subversion server is unavailable and I have two versions of code?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN to manage versioning of a C# application. Suddenly my svn server went down. I have two different versions of the code. How can merge them?

Answer (score 2):

Wait until the server has been restored.

If you **really** need to do this, then:<sup>1</sup>

```
svn diff working_copy_1 > diff.diff
cd working_copy_2
patch -p0 < diff.diff
```

However, this has problems:

- When you finally commit this back to SVN, it will be seen as one commit (there will be no way to separate out the two changesets).
- If the two working copies have different base revisions, then the above merge will either result in nasty conflicts, or will miss out certain changes.

---

<sub>1. This assumes you're working on Linux or similar (which I guess you're not, because you're using TortoiseSVN!)  I don't know what the Windows equivalent of `patch` is, I'll leave you to figure that out.</sub>

Comment: it will take 1-2 more days to restore the server! but i need the solution immediately.

Comment: @RasedDotNet: You can use `svn diff` on one copy and then apply the result as a patch to the other copy, but the result will not be something that SVN will be able to untangle.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already got your answer and may be it is not useful to you but posting this just for information in case others need to have a look at...

If we are working in a large team where many folks are daily using SVN Server for commiting, updating their changes which is to be used in the team and suddenly one fine day we find that our SVN Server is down.

It just gives us a lot of hard time as we need to merge each and every one changes and it is kind of chaotic situation.

**Reason why we are stuck:-**
Since SVN is a CENTRALISED form of versioning system[image]

where every machine is connected to central server. Now if our central server goes down then all are kind of stuck up. [image]

**Solution for the same:-**

Use of Distributed Versioning system like GIT, Mercurial, Bazaar, etc.

**Reason why it is helpful:-**

Unlike Centralised system where every machine is only connected to Central server only, in distributed versioning system each machine can be connected to each other as well. Its basically a kind of local repository itself is formed on individual's machine.

[image]

**Advantage we get here:-**

If our central server goes down, then a changes made by Client1 can be updated by Client2 by connecting to Client1 and so on.

[image]

So now we don't have to wait for our central server to be available. We can continue with our normal work and once our server is available the code can be commited onto it.

Comment: Don't forget there are ways to cluster Subversion and setup MultiSite so you can tolerate a failure.  With DVCS if your "central" server goes down you still have work to do to talk to the other users and it's more work and more confusing than if a load balancer automatically switched you over to the other "central" server.